# How to find out the file name of webpage?

Tags: php

It is possible to find out the script file name only through PHP. `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` gives full path including the file name. I want just the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it in conjunction with `basename()`

`basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function to get file name:

```
echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

**More Info:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Answer (score 0):

You may use one of the following:

```
echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ;
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ;
echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ;
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ;
```

plus [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)():

```
echo basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) ;
echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ;
echo basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) ;
echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ;
```

Comment: The names in [] should be quoted. PHP will cope with them unquoted due to backward compatibility, but if you don't use quotes in your array element names, you run the risk of ambiguity with Constants.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `print_r` of $_SERVER (or use `phpinfo()`), and you'll see there's a whole load of variables to deal with this.

Here are some of them:

- SCRIPT_NAME - Contains the current script's path.
- SCRIPT_FILENAME - The absolute pathname of the currently executing script.
- REQUEST_URI - The URI which was given in order to access this page.

Depending on how your site is written and hosted, these three may contain similar or quite different values. The most likely one to direclty replace PHP_SELF is REQUEST_URI, but it depends on what you're trying to achieve with it.

Also, many places where PHP_SELF is used could just as easily be done without specifying anything -- eg a form pointing back to the same page can just have action of "" rather than needing to specify anything.

The [PHP manual page for $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) also lists all the available options.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the magic constant `__FILE__`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]
```

Comment: `SCRIPT_NAME` still returns `/dir/filename.php`

Comment: Would this also give the full path + file name? I think the OP wants something (if it exists) that will give ONLY the file name!!

Comment: and that's correct, use your imagination to retrieve the file name

Comment: So, how is that any different from the original question that is being asked?

Comment: PHP_SELF returns the filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root. For instance, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in a script at the address http://example.com/test.php/foo.bar  would be /test.php/foo.bar. BUT in case you have a Rewrite from apache it wouldn't give you the php file that is executed. mr nepal asked for the file name, not the "http translated" file name, ok?

Comment: But your solution does not give him the file name, it gives him a _slightly_ shorter version of his own answer...